# How to make custom auto-replies in Skype for specific group?

Tags: if-this-then-that, automation, skype-for-web

I have a chat-group with my colleagues concerning the server and services restart occurrences and what I want to achieve is when my Skype is under specific status (`Away`, `Offline`) to automatically reply with a certain message. Optimally to respond based on the message of the sender (for example, when someone of the group sends message:

> Server restart on servers {3,4}. Please confirm that the restart can be initiated.

and my Skype is `Away` or `Offline`, my Skype account to reply with message:

> User myuser does not use the application currently, please continue with the restart.

I attempted to use IFTT but the only applets that are available are the ones created by Skype.

Answer (score 2):

Since Skype does not have such functionality built-in IMO your Q may be too broad to be suitable for WA.

From [Carola Clavo](https://www.quora.com/Does-Skype-have-an-auto-reply-option-or-an-out-of-office-option) Sep 27, 2016:

> Skype doesn't have an auto-reply feature via chat, but it can respond
>   to calls automatically the person that calls you if you record a
>   message. Like an answering machine, people will hear an automated
>   message or your voice if you enable voice mail.
>
> Also you can use third party apps like [Pamela for Skype](http://www.pamela.biz/en/) and have more
>   advanced features like an “out of the office” chat message, and more.

Comment: I've added an IFTTT applet where the IFTTT sends every day at a certain time the weather prediction for the day, for the location I am located and the Skype application identified the IFTTT messages as bots participants in the chat https://goo.gl/XP52cP.

Comment: does that really work?